General question on achieving second order convergence in a numerical algorithm, does every local step need second order convergence?
I have a spatial and temporal discretization method, that transfer data from particle to grid and then transfer back. I have a time discretization scheme that achieve 2nd order convergence and a spatial scheme that also achieve 2nd order convergence. But some local transformation from grid to particle is not 2nd order, should I consider that as a problem?
